# Login to website via php in three steps

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I can login to website via PHP and grab contents and do the other stuff. See my coding:

```
    <?php

    //Upload a blank cookie.txt to the same directory as this file with a CHMOD/Permission to 777
    function login($url,$data){
        $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
        fclose($fp);
        $login = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($login);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($login);
        unset($login);    
    }                  

    function grab_page($site){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($ch);
    }

    function post_data($site,$data){
        $datapost = curl_init();
            $headers = array("Expect:");
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
            curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($datapost);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($datapost);
        unset($datapost);    
    }
?>
<?php
    //for grabbing:
  echo function grab_page("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/#identifier");
   ?>
And for login it is:
<?php
    function login(https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/#identifier,username and password){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
?>
```

This stuff is simply grab the page and login automatically and working correctly and can work in most websites.
Issue is that the website I'm trying to login is 3 step,means after entering username and password it gives me screen like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVjxK.png to tick the image and enter password.
Even after entering that,it gives new screen like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K71wp.png and it comes out randomly every time I login as another one: i.imgur.com/Ee85kre.png
Issue is how can i login crossing all obstacles like these via PHP curl.I searched Google but even only simply login script came.Please suggest something.

Comment: Actually website is in java

Comment: if someone has put this security in login access then you can not do it simply by crossing them, you need to clear all the security checks

Comment: that site is designed to prevent scripts from accessing. had you checked what you are trying to do is legal?

Comment: Yup,this is legal infact many software do that login but i wanna in site only.

Comment: @ShivaniMishra think logically, anyone who build the site to which you are trying login into, they are not allowing their own users to login without clearing all security checks, then why would they allow you to login without the security checks? And btw after checking your screenshots it seems like the website is somewhere related to money transactions, I strongly recommend you to force users to clear all security checks.. best luck

Comment: Ok @NishantSolanki so how can i check or force users via script to security check.Any link,any source you know?

Comment: @ShivaniMishra I didn't get it, user just needs to give the right answers of security checks and website/application should open up

Answer (score 0):

You coould try something with a token that is connected in your database to the user. A unique one for every user that is.

When registering, you could create one with use of username, password ip and a salt. You then mail a link to the new user with the token in the url, which when picked up by your script, log the user in when all settings are correct.

Comment: I did it once, worked like a charm. Only drawback is, is that other people could use the link as well. So if you site contains critical data I would advise against it.